How to configure elasticsearch on aws instance?
I'm trying to configure Elasticsearch on the AWS server.
I only have SSH access and have installed Elasticsearch manually by CLI. now I have to configure Elasticsearch on the Magento admin side but it gives me
"class not found error"
this is the file setting

/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml


and when I run this command I get this output

curl -X GET "localhost:9200"

{
  "name" : "some ip",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "some uid",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "some number",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

I have removed and changed some info for security reasons.
this is the error I'm getting on admin side



uncomment the

http.port

line and restart your apache server

sudo service apachae2 restart

refresh the admin page.

save the config, clear config cache and test connection
see the screenshort below:


for admin config :


->go to store -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> Catalog Search, find elasticsearch config for Server Port should be 9200,
Search Engine should be elasticsearch, Elasticsearch Server Hostname
should be  http://127.0.0.1


How do I find the hostname and port for admin configuration?

check the updated answer
